# Error inserting row to the sql server from linqtosql with the existance of a trigger

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql, triggers, insert

I created a trigger for the table below in the sql server,

```
Buildings: ID decimal(24, 0) PK, Name varchar(255)
```

The trigger is

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TRG_BLD]
   ON  [dbo].[Building] 
   INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Building (Name)
    SELECT Name
    FROM inserted
END
```

All it does, only inserting the row into the table (it does more, but I'm trying to simplify my case).

When I'm inserting a row from the sql server, everything is fine,
but when I'm inserting through LinqToSql,

```
Building b = new Building();
b.Name = "building A";
DC.Buildings.InsertOnSubmit(b);
DC.SubmitChanges();
```

an exception occurs on 'SubmitChanges' saying :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.Linq.dll
>
> Additional information: The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Decimal which is a non-nullable value type.

Comment: You are not supplying a value for the primary key. If it does not have to be a decimal use an IDENTITY field. Or you are going to have to come up with a method of generating unique values for it

Comment: @SimonWilson I changed the type of the ID to int, though it was already auto-incremented Identity, but I'm still getting the following error: "
The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Int32 which is a non-nullable value type."

Comment: @AhmadHammoud you need to change your Entity to Int32 as well. and add `Property(x => x.ID).HasColumnName("ID").IsRequired().HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);` to your entity configuration

Answer (score 0):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Building', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.Building
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.Building
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(255)
)
GO
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix ON dbo.Building (Name) WITH(IGNORE_DUP_KEY=ON)
GO

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.TRG_BLD
   ON  dbo.Building
   INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO dbo.Building (Name)
    SELECT Name
    FROM INSERTED

END
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Building (Name)
VALUES ('a'), ('a'), ('b'), ('c'), (NULL), (NULL)
GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.Building
```

output -

```
ID          Name
----------- ------------
1           a
3           b
4           c
5           NULL
```

Comment: I just tried it, but I'm still getting this error.. "An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.Linq.dll
Additional information: The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Decimal which is a non-nullable value type."

Comment: please note that `ID` is `INT`. change your code and check again

Comment: I have exactly the same error too, and the primary key column in my table is of type INT, couldn't find a solution for it yet

Comment: @Devart I ran the same code you provided me, and tested it, but still the same exception,
I even tried it on another PC, a different project with a different database, the same..
maybe is it something with the LinqToSql?

Comment: @Devart my problem is not from sql-server, everything is working fine to me when I insert from the sql management studio, My problem is when I'm using LinqToSql to insert.

Comment: @Devart Would you mind explaining what your code should fix? I don't see much of a difference.

Comment: just added a unique index which avoids duplication in `dbo.Building`

Comment: The issue is that the trigger hides `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` from linq-to-sql. So after the insert, linq-to-sql receives null from the database and tries to assign that value to a decimal.

Comment: @GertArnold So there's no solution for my problem?

Comment: You could consider moving to Entity Framework in which it's peanuts to use sprocs for CUD actions, while the basic architecture closely resembles linq-to-sql.